# Change WooCommerce thankyou page title based on order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, orders

Attempting to change the title of the thank you page based on specific order statuses, by combining a filter and action as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'order_thank_you_status' );

function order_thank_you_status( $order_id ){

    // Get an instance of the `WC_Order` Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // Get the order number
    $order_number  = $order->get_order_number();
    // Get the order status name
    $status_name  = wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() );
    // Get the order key
    $test_order_key = $order->get_order_key();

    if ( $order->has_status('on-hold') || $order->has_status('mockup-requested') || $order->has_status('mockup-sent')|| $order->has_status('mockup-approved')) {
        echo 'helllo world';

        add_filter( 'the_title', 'woo_title_order_received', 10, 2 );
        function woo_title_order_received( $title, $id ) {
            if ( function_exists( 'is_order_received_page' ) &&
                is_order_received_page() && get_the_ID() === $id ) {
                $title = "Mockup request received";
            }
            return $title;
        }
    }
}
```

but I have tried multiple ways to combine the two and without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to change "Order received" page title based on order statuses:

```
add_action( 'the_title', 'change_order_received_page_title_based_on_order_status' );
function change_order_received_page_title_based_on_order_status( $title ){
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') && $title === 'Order received' ) {
        global $wp;

        $targeted_statuses = array('on-hold', 'mockup-requested', 'mockup-sent', 'mockup-approved' );

        // Get an instance of the `WC_Order` Object
        $order = wc_get_order( absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']) );

        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) && in_array( $order->get_status(), $targeted_statuses ) ) {
            return __("Mockup request received", "woocommerce");
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Excellent this is useful, Now I can go through and set the thank you page to display each stage/status on change. I removed `&& $title === Order received` for my use case again and it worked. For anyone who's interested viewing the order on the thank you page with the stages or status allows the customer to check the order status with out logging in since the `order_key` is used in the status change notification emails.